# How to set a div hight to a certain percent of a window height using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, height

A rather basic question, I guess, but I want help with it.

I need to set up the height of div to 70% of the height of the browser window, and I want to do it with jQuery.

What's the best code for that?

Thank you for your help!

Dimitri Vorontzov

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$('#theDiv').height(function(){
   return $(window).height() * 0.7;
});
```

Comment: Thank you Reigel, that's exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Via Viewport-percentage lengths:

```
 height:70vh;
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lztggxpk/1/

For more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths